# Use Dish Network with a TV tuner: how?

Tags: tuner-card, satellite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Satellite TV on my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/124620/satellite-tv-on-my-pc)

I talked to someone at Dish, and they said I must have a TV to use their receiver. So PC can't decode their signals? What if I use a TV tuner? What other options do I have to use Dish Network with a computer, rather than a TV?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Satellite TV on my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/124620/satellite-tv-on-my-pc) for HD perhaps also check out [High-def TV tuner for satellite TV](http://superuser.com/questions/2391/high-def-tv-tuner-for-ellite-tv)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be using a TV tuner card, connecting the Dish Network receiver to it.

It might work with a DVB card, but I don't know if they can deal with encrypted signals.

Comment: is there a requirement or any tv tuner card will work?

Comment: I don't know; I assume any TV card will work.