# Watching satellite tv from laptop's monitor

Tags: laptop, hdmi, tv, satellite

I have a satellite TV decoder with the following plugs:

[image: 1]

which are HDMI, RS232, TV/VCR, TV SCART plugs respectively. I'd like to watch TV on my laptop (an ASUS S550C).

I was told that it's not possible to connect this directly to my laptop via an HDMI cable (laptops have output-only HDMI plugs) so I was thinking of buying this:

http://www.hauppauge.com/site/products/data_hvr950q.html

My question is: I don't see any HDMI support in the webpage above, so can I plug my satellite decoder somehow and watch it on my PC with this TV stick? Perhaps using TV/VCR cable?

Comment: I think the most proabable answer is no, but I don't know everything so I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use Dish Network with a TV tuner: how?](http://superuser.com/questions/434827/use-dish-network-with-a-tv-tuner-how)

Answer (score 1):

Your satellite has a decryption chip on it to unscramble the signal, which no tv tuner card could do, unless from your satellite provider. Once the signal goes through your receiver though, it can be passed through via any connection on the box. So if you're receiver outputs coaxial, then you can use the product you link to. But you can't plug directly in to the computer from the dish and have it work.

Comment: Do you mean an intermediate device is required between coaxial and laptop? if so, what should that be?

Comment: There are some tv tuner cards you can buy. Asking which ones would be out of scope for super user, but could be asked on hw recs.

Answer (score 0):

You could also look for a "USB Video Capture" device, it is used by many to set up a gaming console (eg PlayStation 3, Xbox 360) on a laptop.